# How can I edit the client-menu menu of openbox? (invoked by alt + space)

Tags: openbox

I would like to remove the following items in the openbox client menu:

- Send to Desktop
- Restore
- Move
- Resize
- Iconify
- Maximize
- Roll up/down
- Un/Decorate

This is the menu you can invoke by right clicking on the window decorations or with <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>.

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

This menu is called the [client-menu](http://openbox.org/wiki/Help%3aActions#ShowMenu). Unfortunately there's no way to change the entries aside from modifiyng the source code.

However, if I understood you correctly you want to remove all menu entries aside from the ones pertaining to the window layer. In that case you can assign a shortcut to the `client-layer-menu`.

Open your openbox `rc.xml` (usually under `$HOME/.config/openbox/rc.xml`, might be called `lxde-rc.xml` or `lubuntu-rc.xml` depending on your DE). Find the following line:

```
<keybind key="A-space"><action name="ShowMenu"><menu>client-menu</menu></action></keybind>
```

and replace it with:

```
<keybind key="A-Space"><action name="ShowMenu"><menu>client-layer-menu</menu></action></keybind>
```

As for the window close option you lost by replacing the menus: You can always use the <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> shortcut.